# Android WebView and default browser with different UserAgent

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

From some reason on several android devices, I'm getting different User Agent from the browser and from my application's WebView.

I have used this line of code to get the UA in the app:

```
new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

This is the part with the difference

The application retruns:

> HTC One X Build

While the browser returns:

> HTC_One_X Build

Notice the underscores in the browser's version.

Any ideas what causes the difference?

Tx!